# Android Toolbar too high in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-toolbar

My min and target sdk is 21, and I am not using the support library.

I am using the new Toolbar widget, and generally it works, I just have a glitch in the way it looks. The action icons are centered in portrait mode, whereas the toolbar in landscape mode is higher, and the icons are not centered. Please take a look at the screenshots (read lines are just to make the problem more visible):

- portrait:

[image: portrait mode]

- landscape:

[image: landscape mode]

This might look like nothing, but when the actions are selected (like the 'up' arrow at the very left of the bar) the result is that a strip of few pixels below it is visible. I don't like the way it looks.

The activity does not manage any configuration changes itself.

This is my code:

- styles.xml:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>

      <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
          <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolbarStyle</item>
      </style>

      <style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="android:Widget.Toolbar">
          <item name="android:background">?android:attr/colorPrimary</item>
          <item name="android:elevation">2dp</item>
      </style>

  </resources>
  ```
- XML usage:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  tools:context="com.test.TestActivity">

      <Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

I tried messing around with the android:minHeight attribute, but setting to so, say, 30dp just moved the icons even more upwards, also in portrait mode.

I found this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77874
But there is no ?attr/actionBarSize...

How, if at all, can this problem be fixed? The phone the screenshots were taken on is a Nexus 6 (xxxhdpi), and the icon is from the google icon pack, and the biggest resource is xxhdpi. Is this the problem?

**Update**: the workaround from the aforementioned link does work when I use ?android:attr/actionBarSize. But, is this the only way? Seems a bit wrong, to need such workarounds for a new shiny component like this, even more so that the workaround requires an attribute value for a component to be replaced by the new one.

Comment: Could you plz show your implementation in java code ?
Also I did not see the using of your style ?

Comment: There is no relevant Java code for this. The style is set in AndroidManifest.xml as the theme for the whole application, so every Toolbar in the app uses the 'MyToolbarStyle' style.

Comment: In my opinion, Toolbar is not only used as we are used to use ActionBar, but it can be much taller and display other things inside etc... 
Classic ActionBar shrinks in size on landscape orientation and thus moves icons upwards a little. When using Toolbar, icons still get shifted, but the size is up to you to specify. Now if you want a tall Toolbar, you probably don't want to change the size of the Toolbar - out of your control.
Only specifying "?android:attr/actionBarSize" seems quite okay to me :)

Answer (score 3):

try to use:

```
android:height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

for your toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your toolbar style:

```
<item name="maxButtonHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.

My solution:

Put your toolbar into a RelativeLayout with the height you want for your toolbar. Set your toolbars layout_height to "wrap_content" and align it to the vertical center. I hope it helps.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```